# Problems with accents in @html.Enconde(ViewData["Feedback"])

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I'm having prolemas with accents when they step values ​​to ViewData.

In Controller:

`ViewData["mensagem"] = "Não Esta Correto"`

In View:

`@Html.Encode(ViewData["mensagem"])`

appears the : `N&#227;o Esta Correto`

Only the string that is passed by the ViewData have this problem, how to fix .

Comment: According to this, it's the correct encoding of that character for HTML.  Why is this a problem? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e3/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ already encodes. This is the main diff between razor and aspx ... You are double encoding.

```
@ViewData["mensagem"]
```

To NOT encode:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewData["mensagem"])
```